# Is there a way to delete variables through a function?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I wrote a function to delete variables, but I think it is deleting in local scope. How do I ensure it is deleted globally as well?

```py
import torch
import gc

def free_gpu_memory(
    *args,
) -> None:
    """Delete all variables from the GPU. Clear cache.
    Args:
        model ([type], optional): [description]. Defaults to None.
        optimizer (torch.optim, optional): [description]. Defaults to None.
        scheduler (torch.optim.lr_scheduler, optional): [description]. Defaults to None.
    """

    if args is not None:
        # Delete all other variables
        for arg in args:
            del arg

    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

The following is what I do usually, but it gets hefty when variables stack up.

```py
a = 3
del a
```

The above function will not work since it does not delete globally.

```py
# Example
def train_one_epoch():
    a = 3
    b = 2
    free_gpu_memory(a, b)

def train_loop():
    for i in range(num):
        train_one_epoch
```

As the example above, I wish to delete all the variables after each for loop.

Comment: Are the variables you try to delete in the blobal scope?

Comment: Have you tried `del globals()[variable]` from here https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-erase-all-declared-global-variables-in-python